# API or database for verifying chemical reactions

Tags: physical-chemistry, databases

Is there a database or API(rest calls) for verifying chemical equations?
Example, 
Na + Cl -> NaCl + Loss of energy. 
 
So if I want to verify if there is a loss of energy or gain of energy?
Is there any online portal where I can write a chemical equation like above and verify whether its correct or not?
I know there are lots of paid and open source databases. Would be very much helpful if someone can point to me to top databases or sites.

Comment: I fear this may attract downvotes. You should add much more details on the why and what of the problem.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: For a sense of why this is not easily feasible, should I accept the inputs from your example? Sodium: in what state? Chlorine: as a single atom? Or should it be in standard dichlorine form? Sodium chloride, in what state? Solid, in solution, or gas phase? Who's to say what's right?